# MERGE INTO error "Duplicate row detected during DML action" but no duplicate rows found

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm doing a `MERGE INTO` a table on the `ID` column:

```
MERGE INTO mytable AS m
USING (
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_LTZ AS col1, METADATA$FILENAME AS col2, METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER AS col3, TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(METADATA$FILENAME, '\\d{8}'), 'YYYYMMDD') AS col4, $1 AS col5, $2 AS col6 ...
    FROM @deve/20221005.csv (file_format => 'our_file_format')
) AS s
ON m.Id = s.col6
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET m.x = s.col1, m.y = s.col2, m.z = s.col3, m.w = s.col4, x1 = s.col5, m.Id = s.col6, ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (x, y, z, w, x1, Id ... ) VALUES (s.col1, s.col2, s.col3, s.col4, s.col5, s.col6, ...);
```

I checked in snowflake for the ID that populated in the error message and I found only 1 row of the ID, not multiple. So what would be another reason for the message and has anyone found a way to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate value exists at the source level query. Here col6 in CSV file. Ideally the join column should be unique before trying to perform merge.

It is possible to silently accept nondeterministic merge with parameter: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#error-on-nondeterministic-merge